# speech to text throws error Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Speech to text throws an error after some time:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=OutOfRange, Detail="Audio
>   Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be
>   sent close to real time.")

Another error is:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Cancelled, Detail="The
>   operation was cancelled.")

How to avoid these errors? Both the errors are at function:

```cs
if (firstMessage == false) {
    // var buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
    var buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = await outputStream.ReadAsync(
            buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {

        await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
            new StreamingRecognizeRequest() {
                AudioContent = Google.Protobuf.ByteString
                    .CopyFrom(buffer, 0, bytesRead),
            });
        // await Task.Delay(100);
    };

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must be doing some speech recognition from a [streaming input](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize). This error usually occurs when there's a period of silence (e.g 10 seconds or more) in your streaming input, thus, it signals the end of the recognition and cancels the operation. To avoid, make sure to send inputs close to real time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am trying to transcribe live video for which I am using ffmpeg to extract audio and then sending it to api. api returns first 9-10 lines and then throws this error operation cancelled. I am creating new request when receive isfinal true from API. in this case it continue sending transcription but then it simply ignore audio bytes in between. can you tell me how to fix this? how to manage sending new request which will not ignore any bytes instead continue from where it throws error?

Comment: Hey @Dombivali , Did you fix this issue? I'm getting the same error as you describe in the question.

Comment: that does not help. What if you dont know if user keeps silent for long. What to do in those situations?